# How to call a big Stored procedure in Qlikview having 3 parameter

Tags: qlikview

I have a stored procedure which contains 3 input parameters with multiple `SELECT`s and `INNER JOIN`s. I want to Call the stored procedure in QlikView. I followed lots of tutorials, but I make it work.

I am Using OLE DB and I'm trying to call as follows:

```
SQL CALL [DB NAME].[dbo].[ABC] @_ End-Time ='2012-12-31 00:21:06.550', @_ Start-time = '2012-12-31 00:21:06.550',
@_ Username = 'XYZ';
```

Is this correct? If not, what are the ways to call stored procedures into Qlikview and what permission do I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure that you checked this thread (http://goo.gl/IiGD2) but it might be useful. Couple of things that i'm noticing from it: there is additional string that need to be added to the connection string "(mode is write)" and also to activate the "Open Databases in Read and Write mode" in qv. 
Also make sure that you have sql rights to execute.

Regards!
Stefan

Comment: sorry for late reply but i tried the link you had mentions in that. also my idea is to create a qvd file of given stored procedure. for that i need to resolve varriable anyhow ? but don't know how to do this ?????

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to retrieve the three input variables from a table instead, and update this table from qlikview using SQL insert.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to run an store procedure from QlikView, but it is not possible to pull any output you get from it. You should convert that to a function if you want to retrieve any data from QlikView.
Creating a MV is your best course of action, and you will have a better performance.